# Why isnt jQuery setting my value?

Tags: jquery

So here is my code. I am trying to set the value of a hidden form input.

```
if($gender == "BOY" || $gender == "MALE" || $gender == "M" || $gender == "1") {
        console.log('Its a boy!');
        $(".girlsonly").hide();
        document.getElementsByName('dressjacket')[0].placeholder='Jacket';
        $('#majorgender').val('1');
    };
    if($gender == "GIRL" || $gender == "FEMALE" || $gender == "F" || $gender == "0") {
        console.log('Its a girl!');
        document.getElementsByName('dressjacket')[0].placeholder='Dress';
        $('#majorgender').val('0');
    };
```

Here is the form input:

```
<input type="hidden" name="majorgender" id="majorgender"></input>
```

It successfully logs "Its a girl!" or "Its a boy!" but afterwards when I insert "`alert($('majorgender').val());`" it alerts "**undefined**"

If I log `alert($('majorgender'))` it replies with "object Object" so I know it exists, I just dont know why its not setting properly.

Any thoughts?

Comment: `alert($('foobarBARBAR'))` alerts `object Object` too, and obviously it doesn't exist. To test for existence, test the length property of the jquery object. `alert($('foobarBARBAR').length)`

Comment: Do you do an `alert($('majorgender').val())` or an `alert($('#majorgender').val())`?

Comment: Do you access them after DOM is ready?

Comment: alert( $('#majorgender').attr('name') );
If this return correct value, then it exists. Else, move you jQuery code to below the <body> tag

Comment: input is a self closing tag. You don't need </input> in there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are alerting the input `majorgender` like this `$('majorgender').val()`
When really you need to alert it like this `$('#majorgender').val()`

Because you are selecting this input by id you must precede the selector name by a hash `#`

And note that jquery define every selector even if it is not valid as object so it is not necessary if your log show an object that means that your selector is correct and exists :)

Try and tell me if that was helpful :)

Answer (score 7):

You need a `#` in - `alert($('#majorgender').val());` - otherwise it is looking for a tag called majorgender as opposed to an ID

ie. you are currently looking for `<majorgender...`

Comment: @Rick Bross : If this it was the most helpfull answer so please accept it otherwise accept the answer that make sense to you and solve your problem and if your problem is not solved tell us so we can help you better more :)

Answer (score 1):

you missed # changed to

```
alert($('majorgender').val());
```

to

```
alert($('#majorgender').val());
```